# Unable to mount BitLocker 2 encrypted NTFS partition using the new `ntfs3` driver found in Linux 5.15 Kernel

Tags: linux, ntfs, bitlocker

I made a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, which comes with the new [`ntfs3`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.15/filesystems/ntfs3.html) driver

```bsh
$ uname -a
Linux HRK-HPZBOOK 5.15.0-27-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 14 04:55:28 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I was able to open BitLocker 2 encrypted NTFS partition using [`cryptsetup`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/cryptsetup.8.html#bitlk%20(windows%20bitlocker-compatible)%20extension%20(experimental)) command

```bsh
$ sudo cryptsetup bitlkOpen /dev/nvme0n1p5 common-data-crypt
```

But, I get following error when I am mounting the opened partition

```bsh
$ sudo mount -t ntfs3 /dev/mapper/common-data-crypt /mnt/common-data
mount: /mnt/common-data: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/common-data-crypt, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Due to this, I am still stuck on the old [`ntfs-3g`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/ntfs-3g.8.html) driver.

Is anybody else facing this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that driver is supposed to support BitLocker? There also isn’t anything wrong with ntfs-3g

Comment: @Ramhound No, I couldn't find anything about BitLocker support in the new ntfs3 driver.